# Android:How to retain change in color of ListView row?

Tags: android, listview

In my one of the ListView activity i am changing color of 1 or more row on click, but i want to retain this change in color of row, when i come back to this activity again. so how to save and retrieve change in color of row in ListActivity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have your color changed of the clicked rows than, you have to somehow save the state for the rows(if it is clicked or not) as @mak_just4anything suggested to you the best suitable datatype for you is array list of booleans. This list you can save it in sqlite database of maybe use a key value pairs of preferences. But it is very important to note that you need to notify you adapter for the data changed. After the adapter is refreshed ( I guess you will do this in onCreate or in onResume callback) then you will see the listview with right coloring

Comment: Thanks.I am using sqlite table as data source for ListView. It may be possible that on diffrent conditions,app will retrieve diffrent data and map on ListVIew, so i will get changed row color for diffrent data.Is it possible to save particular instant of ListView with particular dataset?

Comment: I do not know maybe there is some serilizations in android for saving an instance of an object , but I will mention again you should save the date somewhere than the adapter should be notified and the listview will be updated accordingly. You shouldn't change the listview it self

Answer (score 0):

Take an array of booleans, and make the indexes of items and boolean same, it means you will have boolean array corresponding to the array of items, when ever you click on item change the boolean value to true so it will be saved in that index and whenever you come back you will find the same array with colored items corresponding to the boolean array....!

Comment: Thanks,good idea, but i am using sqlite table as data source for ListView. It may be possible that on diffrent conditions,app will retrieve diffrent data and map on ListVIew, so i will get changed row color for diffrent data.Is it possible to save particular instant of ListView with particular dataset?

Comment: Then put the another field in database which contains the boolean value... instead of taking an array of the booleans in program..!!